# How to use commas in these types of sentences? How to use the verb have in this type of sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, experiential-have

Here is a sentence:

> In addition, the university's culture, and the strong emphasis on, and a long track record of research strongly speak to me.

I am rather confused if there should be a comma before or after the word research, if at all?

Now, I have another question, here, I am going to use another example from a letter to a school I am writing, but I have this issue in general:

> In addition to continuing my involvement at my local clinic, I have been volunteering at the nearby Level I Trauma Center for the past five months, which has allowed me to mature further in patient-facing roles and *has* intensified my resolve to pursue medicine.

This is about "has," should I include the has in italics? My gut says yet but grammar software says no?

Comment: The first sentence is unclear.  The strong emphasis on *what*?  Is there a word missing?

Comment: I want to mean, that the university in question has a long track record of great research as well as a strong emphasis on research, I am not sure if my sentence construction is proper.

Comment: I understand now, thanks.  Commas can make this kind of sentence very confusing sometimes!

Comment: No problem, do you have any advice for formatting this better, then? This is exactly what I am unsure about.

Comment: @LatticeExpansion In your letter, the **has** in question is optional. Bear in mind that such sentences benefit from being shorter and snappier. **In addition to my continuing involvement at the local clinic, I have been volunteering for five months at the Level 1 Trauma Centre; this has allowed me etc... Caps for Trauma Centre only if it's a title.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.